# How to create multiple dictionaries from a list of strings?

Tags: kdb

I have a variable that contains a list of strings. For each string in the list I would like to create a new dictionary, then update each dictionary with that string value. This would result in 100 new dictionaries being created. For example my variable looks similar to this...

```
q)stock
"APPL"
"TSLA"
"AMZN"
"MSFT"
"NVDA"
..
q)count stock
100
```

I know how to do this for a single string in a variable...

```
q)newdict:()!()
q)stock:"AAPL"
q)newdict[`ticker]:stock
q)newdict
ticker|"AAPL"
```

But how would I do this for a variable that is a list of 100 strings? Also, if I wanted to update the dictionary to include additional `key:value` pairs from another variable with the same count (like below) what is the correct syntax to use for this operation?

```
q)date
2019.05.23T13:03:55.271474000 2019.05.23T13:03:55.271474000...
q)count date
100
```

Expected output for each string in variable would create a new dictionary similar to the following...

```
q)newdictAPPL
ticker|"APPL"
datetime|2019.05.23T13:03:55.271474000

q)newdictTSLA
ticker|"TSLA"
datetime|2019.05.23T13:05:33.727845200

q)newdictAMZN
ticker|"AMZN"
datetime|2019.05.23T13:08:27.742968000
```

Comment: Can you explain your expected output a little more? Do you want a table (which in 
kdb is simply a list of dictionaries)? Also, your `stock` variable contains 100 *strings*, not 100 *characters* (a string is a list of characters)

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan. Updated character to string and included an example of the expected outcome. A table would work fine as well, as long as I can then create individual dictionaries from that table and serialize each back to a json object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're most likely to be interested in is a table. Starting with some sample data similar to what you have:

```
q)stock:20?("AAPL";"TSLA";"MSFT";"AMZN")
q)date:20?.z.Z
q)0N!stock;
("AMZN";"MSFT";"AMZN";"MSFT";"AAPL";"TSLA";"TSLA";"MSFT";"TSLA";"AAPL";"TSLA"..
q)date
2016.09.16T16:06:23.573 2010.10.04T23:28:53.863 2001.03.12T15:16:04.379 2005...
```

We can construct table quite simply in kdb:

```
q)t:([]ticker:stock;datetime:date)
q)t
ticker datetime               
------------------------------
"AMZN" 2016.09.16T16:06:23.573
"MSFT" 2010.10.04T23:28:53.863
"AMZN" 2001.03.12T15:16:04.379
"MSFT" 2005.07.17T04:02:58.577
"AAPL" 2012.12.17T10:48:15.839
"TSLA" 2017.09.16T11:06:02.579
"TSLA" 2002.11.18T00:03:57.945
"MSFT" 2009.06.02T08:28:32.680
"TSLA" 2013.10.24T06:50:31.420
"AAPL" 2007.06.12T07:04:33.058
"TSLA" 2006.08.10T03:45:58.748
"AAPL" 2001.01.17T11:04:57.387
"AAPL" 2010.08.29T21:47:39.564
"MSFT" 2003.10.19T01:58:58.820
"AMZN" 2010.11.21T00:05:03.256
"MSFT" 2001.05.13T21:03:21.293
"TSLA" 2004.02.13T07:49:57.013
"AAPL" 2015.01.31T08:13:03.986
"MSFT" 2009.05.24T06:34:05.044
"TSLA" 2013.03.28T22:11:03.641
```

We can see that a table in kdb is a list of dictionaries, we can index and get individual dictionaries:

```
q)t[0]
ticker  | "AMZN"
datetime| 2016.09.16T16:06:23.573
q)t[1]
ticker  | "MSFT"
datetime| 2010.10.04T23:28:53.863
```

We can also serialise to JSON using built-in [`.j.j`](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/dotj/#jj-serialize) function:

```
q).j.j t
"[{\"ticker\":\"AMZN\",\"datetime\":\"2016-09-16T16:06:23.573\"},{\"ticker\":..
```

Or if we want each dict as individual JSON strings:

```
q).j.j each t
"{\"ticker\":\"AMZN\",\"datetime\":\"2016-09-16T16:06:23.573\"}"
"{\"ticker\":\"MSFT\",\"datetime\":\"2010-10-04T23:28:53.863\"}"
"{\"ticker\":\"AMZN\",\"datetime\":\"2001-03-12T15:16:04.379\"}"
"{\"ticker\":\"MSFT\",\"datetime\":\"2005-07-17T04:02:58.577\"}"
"{\"ticker\":\"AAPL\",\"datetime\":\"2012-12-17T10:48:15.839\"}"
"{\"ticker\":\"TSLA\",\"datetime\":\"2017-09-16T11:06:02.579\"}"
"{\"ticker\":\"TSLA\",\"datetime\":\"2002-11-18T00:03:57.945\"}"
..
```

Comment: Thanks, Jonathon. That's what I was looking for! I'd give you an upvote buy my lack of "reputation" doesn't allow it.